# magento javascript:void(0) in navigation menu

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I've been trying to add Javascript:void(0)to my magento website's navigation bar for a long time. 
I read many articles about this subject and almost all of them says I should edit

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php or copy this to local folder end edit there.

here one of the popular way that i followed;

```
To remove url, href functionality of the top menu categories, you can take the following steps:

Create some folder as this path: app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block
Copy file Navigation.php from app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block to 
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block
Go to function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()
Replace this code

$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
with this code

if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {
        $html[] = '<a href="[removed]void(0);"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
} else {
        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
}
```

But it didn't work for me. Weirdly even if i delete /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php the navigation menu works just fine. Were it gets the code for working I have no idea.

Maybe you have an idea that can help me. I just want to put Javascript:void(0) to the navigation menu.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get a cached version? Are you sure your code is used? You can change the output of the php to be sure: `$html[] = '<span>changed:' . $this...` you can install a chrome extension called cache killer but maybe PHP caches some things as well so restart httpd and or remove cache files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's issue of cache or Magento Compiler. I suggest you to do the following steps from magento admin.

1. go to `admin->System->Cache Management` and clear/flush all the cache
2. go to `admin->System->Tools->Compilation`. Check if compilation is enabled then disabled it and clear cache again and run your compilation process

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking to solve this, I think the problem is that the code you linked only works on 1.7 and not on 1.9?

The solution i came up with

copy `Topmenu.php` from `app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html` to `app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html` replace on line 131:

```
$html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

to

```
        if ($child->hasChildren()) {
            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href=\'javascript:void(0);\'><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
        }
        else{

           $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
           $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
        }
```

Hope this helps.